# Commute Distance and Time

Tags: meaning

One of the things that I've always been hung up on is explaining the length and distance of my commute.

Example 1: "I had a 25 mile commute by car" does that mean 12.5 miles there and 12.5 miles miles back?

Example 2: "I had a 30 minute commute by car" does that mean 15 minutes there and 15 minutes back?

Comment: In the sense of a round-trip:  a 25 mile commute by car does not necessarily implies that the same distance is covered both ways.it can be 13.5 miles there and 11.5 miles there.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex As you know from your other SE accounts, you are expected to do basic research. The answer you seek is in online dictionaries. Voting to close.

Comment: If you think there is a risk of people misunderstanding your terminology, why don't you just spell out for them exactly what you mean instead of agonizing over how they might be failing to understand you?

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of the word "commute" being used in the round-trip sense. That may vary by region, my experience being from NE USA (commuting to/from NYC part of that time) and SE USA (where my commute is now your hypothetical 12.5 miles).

Comment: Seconded. Also, the word "commute" is generally followed by something else like "how was your commute to work?" or "how was your commute this morning?", so it's usually pretty obvious that the person is talking about the one-way trip.

Comment: I would agree the "to and "from" seem implied.  I would refer to the round trip of any given day as my "commutes" that day.

Answer (score 0):

**Your** **commute** is your trip to work and the verb commute describes making that trip — like your preference to commute by public bus.

- How was your commute to work? (@Kevin Workman)

**A commute** is a journey you take from home to work and back again.

Comment: It's not clear what your intention here is.  In the first sentence you say it's your trip ***to*** work.  In the last you say it's the journey to work ***and back again***.

Answer (score 0):

In NY, we use commute in both senses (one way and round trip):

"I have a twenty mile commute to work each day - I end up commuting a hundred miles a week."